# Making a QgsRasterLayer only render what's available in its cache

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, cache, qgsmapcanvas

I have a QgsRasterLayer:

```
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(...)
```

The user moved the map around a bit and the layer is currently visible.

How can I make QGIS (temporarily) not request new data of this layer when panning/zooming but only use what's currently available in its rendering cache? Other layers should update as usual.

I am not looking for the whole logic around this, just the flag (or whatever) to tell QGIS to use the cached render image for the layer.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;TR: a working method**

A quick method is to copy the raster into a temporary layer and disable the original raster.

This can be accomplished for example by clipping the original raster on its own extents:

`Raster` -> `Extraction` -> `Clip Raster by Extent...`

[image]

The file of the original raster will not be accessed any longer.

If you just need a coarser resolution, subsample the temporary layer, for example via Toolbox -> `Raster calculator`.

**And a non-working one ; )**

FYI, also playing around with various combinations of `mapCanvas().freeze()` and `mapCanvas().setRenderFlag()` did not work.

```
#################
# for reference only
# not working, since it either:
#   1. redraws all layers at the end (after re-enabling the layer) when freeze(False)
#   2. does not refresh anything if freeze(True) is left active

import time

def refresh_layers():
    for layer in qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if ('test_layer' != layer.name()):
            #qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setRenderFlag(True)
            layer.triggerRepaint()
            #qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setRenderFlag(False)
            print(layer , 'refreshed')
        else:
            print(layer , 'not refreshed')

layerList = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test_layer')

#qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().freeze(True)

QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layerList[0]).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)

refresh_layers()
#qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().freeze(False)

qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setRenderFlag(True)
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().setRenderFlag(False)

#time.sleep(2) #not useful
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layerList[0]).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Sadly creating a temporary layer won't be an option for complexity and performance reasons. Special thank you for listing the other options you tried, that were candidates I had in mind too.